# Sum number of pages in Filestack v3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

According to [Filestack Docs](https://www.filestack.com/docs/document-transformations), I want to sum all the number of pages of files that I'm uploading in Filestack, so I use ***output=docinfo:true*** option, that show file info in JSON format, and AJAX like this way:

```
var client = filestack.init('myAPI');
client.pick({
  /* my options */
}).then(function(Blobs){
   var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Blobs));

   for(var i=0; i<result.filesUploaded.length; i++){
     var dataFile = "https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/output=docinfo:true/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;

     $.post("numpage.php",{
        dF: dataFile
     }).success(function(response){
         var np = response++;
         console.log("Total number of pages: "+np);
     });
   }
});
```

**numpage.php**

```
 <?php
   $url = $_POST['dF'];
   $str = file_get_contents($url);
   $json = json_decode($str);
   $obj2 = $json->{'numpages'};

   echo $obj2;
 ?>
```

But in console shows only 1 page, and while I continue uploading files it's still showing 1 page in console. How can I fix it?

I'd like some help. Thanks!